# Is B Movie a genre?

Tags: genre

Is B Movie a genre of it's own? Are there requirements that get a movie thrown into that category or do the producers specifically set out to make it a B movie?

Netflex will list B horror as one of the genres and I know there is a cult following of B movies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I would not classify B-Movie as a genre.  The name came from the fact that it used to be the second movie of a double-bill, and was usually low budget and shorter than the other.

Nowadays we think of a B-Movie in a broader sense of being a low budget commercial movie, and has some overlap with Exploitation movies, but they can cover multiple genres including Horror as you mention. Science Fiction & Westerns are genres that have produced many B-Movies. The Italians were famous for producing 'Peplum' movies - also known as 'Swords and Sandals' movies.

It is true that there was a 'golden age' of B-Movies and that there are certain traits that might make you think 'this is a b-movie', but I do not think they would form a recognized genre in their own right.

Yes, director's would often know they were making a B-Movie - explicitly because it had a low budget and was destined to accompany a main feature.  This might impart some of the characteristics that people love or hate about B-Movies, but it doesn't make it a genre IMHO.

Comment: True. That said, I would suggest that the lines are blurring - many films market themselves as belonging to the B-Movie 'genre' irrespective of the actual genre contained within. It's a little like the whole 'grindhouse' genre - is it really a genre?